# SSRS expression for calculation using a specific value

Tags: ssrs-2008, expression, ssrs-2012, percentage

I've attempted to create an expression which should calculate when a field equals 'Mid' and another equals 'Red' then calculate a percentage based on a field / specific number.

Here are my attempts so far:

```
=count(IIF(Fields!loc.Value="Mid" AND Fields!Status.Value ="Red",1,Nothing)) / count(Fields!Total.Value / 500) *100

=IIF(Fields!loc.Value="Mid" AND Fields!Status.Value="Grey",(FormatPercent    (Count(Fields!Total.Value) / 500 ,0))
```

Expected results from the calculation would be a percentage: 34.83% (to two DP)

Loc field contains locations: Mid, Lon, Manc, Newc etc etc 
Status field contains colours for statuses: Red, Green, Blue, Yellow etc etc 
Total field contains 'total' values for locations.

Neither seem to work and I'm getting myself confused. Once this one part is done, I can then add multiple locations and colours too.

Comment: could you edit your question to include a sample dataset and your expected result?

Comment: Hopefully the additions will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing a dataset like this:

```
Loc    Status    Total
Mid    Red        100
Mid    Red        200
Lon    Blue        90
Manc   Yellow      50
```

And you want to calculate the percentage of occurrences where Loc = "Mid" and Status = "Red" Using an expression like this:

```
=COUNT(
  IIF(Fields!Loc.Value = "Mid" and Fields!Status.Value = "Red",Fields!Loc.Value,Nothing)) /
COUNT(Fields!Loc.Value,"DataSetName")
```

Replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of yours.

You will get `2/4 = 0.5` (50%) if you format the cell to a percentage number.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You definitely lead me to the correct (or what I believe is) expression. I'll add what I added/removed below.

Comment: =sum(IIF(Fields!loc.Value = "Mid" and Fields!Status.Value = "Grey", Fields!Total.Value, Nothing)) / 500 * 100